# Boto doubles all get request cycles by design

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto

To get an object out of S3 using Boto, you have to call something like (at least this is the only documented way I can find):

```
key = bucket.get_key(some_id)
data = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

However, `get_key` does a HEAD, then `get_contents_as_string` does a GET.  This is painfully inefficient. I know the things I'm requesting from S3 will almost always exist (eventual consistency aside, my ratio of there to almost there is enormous; millions:1). Is there some way I can bypass the apparent boto requirement of calling `get_key` and just jump straight to "get me the data associated with this id"?

Comment: It's inefficient but is it really painfully inefficient? :) That would depend on your use case.  Your title sounds a little charged too. Those functions you're using are convenience functions the author has provided for some common tasks and efficiency does not trump usability in the design for that case IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API shows the class used to [instantiate a Key object](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key) directly.

```
key = Key(bucket=bucket, name=my_key_id)
data = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

In my usage of boto so far I've found the docs a useful introduction but very incomplete compared to the generated API documentation.

Comment: I eventually came to this. I just got misled because the samples explicitly show getting a key via `bucket.get_key()`. You get the accepted because this solution is more correct in terms of OO design than garnaat.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

If you know the key is there, you can simply create a Key object like this:

```
key = bucket.new_key(some_id)
data = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

This will allow you to skip the HEAD request to check for the key's existence.  Of course, if the key isn't actually there this will produce a 404 error.